# Continuous mapping $f: [0,1]\rightarrow (0,1)$ CSIR December $2013$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Question is :

Suppose  $f: [0,1]\rightarrow (0,1)$ is Continuous then which of the following is NOT true..

- $F\subseteq[0,1]$ is closed set implies $f(F)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$
- If $f(0)<f(1)$ then $f([0,1])$ must be equal to $[f(0),f(1)]$
- There must exist $x\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x)=x$
- $f([0,1])\neq (0,1)$

Continuous map need not map closed sets to closed sets..

So, first option is not true...

Continuous maps takes connected sets to connected sets ...

So $f([0,1])$ must be connected and it is equal to  $[f(0),f(1)]$.. So, Second option is true..

Continuous maps takes compact sets to compact sets...

So, $f([0,1])\neq (0,1)$ and so fourth option is true...

I guess third option is also false though I can not think of any example..

Continuous map from compact set to itself has a fixed point.

But how do i conclude that this would imply third option is true/false.

Please help me to clear this...

Thank you.

Comment: In general continuous maps don't map closed sets to closed sets, but if $F \subseteq [0,1]$ it is compact, so $f(F)$ is compact and therefore closed.

Comment: When studying the third claim consider Bolzano and the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Together with Michael's comment this leaves option ...

Comment: The second option is not true, consider $f(x) = \frac14\bigl(1 + x(3/2-x)\bigr)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : I could not  understand how did you come up with such an example very fast :O why would my justification is wrong :O Please explain a bit more....

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese : Oh yes... That is a valid point :) Thank you so much... :)

Comment: Praphulla: Just imagine any function that has a maximum (or a minimum) between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I could not understand what was your idea... could you please take some more pain in extending your arguments...

Comment: Eliminating the third option: Show that $g$ is continuous, $g(0)>0$ and $g(1)<0$ and apply Bolzano's theorem (you may know it by the name *intermediate value theorm* - I'm not sure under which name it goes in various parts of the world).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Oh yes... $g(x)=f(x)-x$ implies $g(0)=f(0)>0$ and $g(1)=f(1)-1<0$ thus there exists a point in between $0$ and $1$ such that $g(a)=0$ i.e., $f(a)=a$ Done... Thank you...

Comment: for @2@ just think of an example where you get maximum between $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ and continuous function maps connected to connected doesn't  mean that , that connected set has to be $[f(0),f(1)]$ itself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Constructing the counterexample to (2) is easy. Draw a picture! Can you draw a squiggly line from $f(0)$ to $f(1)$ that goes below $f(0)$ say? That's your counterexample!

Comment: I am sorry, I could not visualize your statement could you please explain a bit more...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Do exactly as I have said. Take a pen out, draw the $x-y$ plane, draw $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ with $f(1) > f(0)$. Now draw a curve connecting the two points, and draw it so that some portion of the curve goes below  the horizontal line $y = f(0)$.

Comment: Oh... I got it :) Thank you.. That was wonderful...

Answer (score 6):

To see that "There must exist $x\in(0,1)$ such that $f(x)=x$" observe that since $f$ is continuous and domain is a closed interval, $f$ is bounded.

Now consider the function

$g(x)=f(x)-x$. It is trivial to show that $g(x)$ is continuous. Now $g(0)=f(0)>0$ and $g(1)=f(1)-1 <0$. By intermediate value theorem there must exist a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $g(c)=0$ which gives the desired result.

Comment: I have solved this in the comments.. Thank you anyways...

Comment: may be you can like it